# Adding property to JSON object in Javascript

Tags: json, xml, node.js, xml2js

I am using `xml2js` to convert `xml` to `js` object and add new nodes to the content

```
Ex1:
<abc>
   <my-node>123</my-node>
   <my-node>456</my-node>
</abc>


Ex2:
<abc>
   <my-node>123</my-node>
</abc>
```

In the `Ex1`, the `my-node` property will be an array whereas in the `Ex2`, it will be non-array item.

How to add extra `my-node` to the same. I can do in below format but looking for better solution?

```
if(typeof abc.my-node == Array){
   abc.my-node.push(xxx);
} else {
   //create empty array
   //add existing element
   //add xxx
   //set the array to json object
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```js
function addProp(obj, propName, value) {
  if (propName in obj) {
    if (obj[propName] instanceof Array) {
      obj[propName].push(value);
    }
    else if (typeof obj[propName] !== 'object') {
      obj[propName] = [obj[propName], value];
    }
  }
  else {
    obj[propName] = value;
  }
}

var abc = {};
console.log(JSON.stringify(abc));
addProp(abc, 'my-node', 123);
console.log(JSON.stringify(abc));
addProp(abc, 'my-node', 456);
console.log(JSON.stringify(abc));
addProp(abc, 'my-node', 789);
console.log(JSON.stringify(abc));
```

then the result is

```
{}
{"my-node":123}
{"my-node":[123,456]}
{"my-node":[123,456,789]}
```

Comment: essentially it's refactored method ;)